# Lua Roblox gui scripting format

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been trying to follow this youtube tutorial about a Sliding Door.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZpD8t8kQC8&ab_channel=Terra

I followed all of the tutorial but the Door still doesn't open.

Here is the script:

```
animator = require(script.Parent.MainDoor.Animator)

script.Parent.Button.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.Button.CLickDetector.MaxActivationDistance = 0
    wait(1)
    script.Parent.MainDoor.Open:Play()
    wait(0.1)
    animator.DoorOpen:Play()

end)
```

Can someone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Try to debug if the code are reached end.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any errors in the output? Go to View > Output, to enable the window

I believe there might be a spelling error on line 4 'CLickDetector'. The l was not capital on line 3 so that might be throwing you an error since names are case-sensitive.

```
script.Parent.Button.CLickDetector.MaxActivationDistance = 0
```

Hope it helped!

In response to:

> main door is not a valid member of model workspace.sliding door

Make sure that the main door is underneath the SlidingDoor model, and not outside it.

Paste this in the command bar(View > Command Bar), to find out what the parent is:

```lua
for _,v in ipairs(workspace:GetDescendants()) do
    if string.lower(v.Name) == "maindoor" then
        print("Found main door, parent is: " .. tostring(v.Parent))
    end
end
```

The result will be shown in the output.

Comment: hi there . I corrected the spelling mistake but it still doesn't work. on the output error is states: "main door is not a valid member of model workspace.sliding door".